# Install Alpine security updates only

Tags: security, package-management, alpine-linux

Is there a way to install only security updates for Alpine Linux and its `apk` packages, skipping updates that don't fix security holes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find two different packages for the same software, in the same branch, one patched and another not.
So, an update generally includes a security fix.

.: Francesco